# How to set background for entire recyclerview and not only the visible part?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a list of items which takes more space than the screen offers and I need to put a background to the entire list. The background should expand to the entire list size, i.e, the background should be shown partially at start, and when scrolling you should see the rest of the background. When I set the background property of the RecyclerView with the drawable item it only expands to the visible part.

Is there a way to make it expand on the entire RecyclerView?

Solution:

I tried the suggestions in the answer and comments:

1. Wrapping the RecyclerView in a layout and giving the drawable to the outer layout still had the background only on the visible part of the list.
2. Putting the items in a LinearLayout which is a child of a NestedScrollView works.
3. After a few trial and error I found another solution: wrap the RecyclerView in a FrameLayout (or probably any other layout) and wrap that in a NestedScrollView:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </FrameLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: The visible part *is* the "entire RecyclerView". If you do not have many items in the list, you could consider using a `LinearLayout` with our background and items, wrapped in a `NestedScrollView` for scrolling.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. It's not a lot of items but the number and the content of items is based on data that often changes so I can't fix a number of items in a LinearLayout. Is there a way to do it for dynamic list of items?

Comment: You can `add()` children to a `LinearLayout` at runtime. You are not limited to using `LinearLayout` solely in a layout resource XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the background on the parent layout that contains the RecyclerView in XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_background">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created demo for show background image in `RecyclerView` and background image should scroll with `RecyclerView` items scrolling.

Add following code for `RecyclerView`, `NestedScrollView` and `LinearLayout`

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_poster">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rclMovie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"               
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_movie" />

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

With this I'm able to sync background image scrolling with `RecyclerView` items.